Change "Listed in" Location on FB Marketplace
I can't seem to be able to change my "listed in" location in FB Marketplace. I recently moved cities and I can't get it updated to my new city.
I've tried changing my FB Profile and Marketplace Profile. I've Googled the question and the responses didn't help.
